# How to open .tar_1 file?

Tags: package-management, files, file-format, archive

I downloaded some firmware packages from Intel.

Two of them installed fine but this one is different and doesn't unpack fully.

It could be the wrong package that I downloaded but I'd like to know for it's own sake why it won't open and what is .tar_1?

(I'm on 16.04 LTS)

[image: Image of the problem]

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the file extension to .tar (which is a common *nix archive format). You can also identify the format of the file using the console command "file":

```
file skldmcver126.tar_1
```

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, using a tar command in the terminal worked just fine.

```
tar -xvf myfile.tar_1
```

While using the archive manager produced an error.